# Why do I get weird shadows on my baked normal map?

Tags: texture-baking, normal-map

I baked a normal map,
however, there's weird shadow.. what is the problem?

The first picture is when I bake the normal map options:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you recalculate your normals? Are all faces the correct way?

Comment: Try baking with subsurf modifier set to 2 maybe?

Comment: It could be the color space of your texture node, it has to be "non-color" for normal maps.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're seeing z fighting which is when you have two nearly identical meshes on top of each other.  You have both dragons visible in the outliner, you should hide one of them.

Comment: I think that's not the way to solve... I try this way twice